# What's the maximum number of elements a scheme list can have?

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

I'm working with Chicken Scheme, I wonder how many elements a list can have.

Comment: Probably min(2147483647,your_computer_memory). Why does it matter anyway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no hard limit – it can have as many as there's room for in memory.

Comment: Or as much as the process is allowed to allocate. eg. I have 16GB ram on my system, but I have set `ulimit` parameters so that one process can allocate no more than 8GB. This hinders the system from being responsive from one crazy process.

Comment: @Sylwester So... as much as there is room for, then?

Comment: With no limit I guess you can allocate much more than your physical memory since most systems have swap space.

Comment: @Sylwester Yes, you can. Do you feel that the distinction between physical and virtual memory is relevant?

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Using%20the%20compiler), under the option `-:hmNUMBER`, it mentions that there is a default max limit of 2GB heap size, which gives you about 45 million pairs. You can increase these with several options, but the simplest for a set default memory limit is `-heap-size`. Here is how to double the default:

```
csc -heap-size 4000M <file>
```

It says under the documentation for `-heap-size` that it only uses half of the allocated memory at every given time. It might be using the lonely hearts garbage collection algorithm where when memory is full it moves used memory to the unused segment making the old segment the unused one.